# Android how to recycle bitmap in Imageview

Tags: android, memory, imageview, android-imageview, android-bitmap

When I click loadBtn(Button), my imageView can  setImageResource(image) .

After I click clearBtn(Button), imageView should clear this image, recycle bitmap, and switch another activity. But I watch Profiler, **Graphics Memory is not released**.

My onClick code:

```
clearBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            recycleImageView(img);
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
    loadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture88);
        }
    });
```

My recycle bitmap code:

```
 public static void recycleImageView(View view){
    if(view==null) return;
    if(view instanceof ImageView){
        Drawable drawable=((ImageView) view).getDrawable();
        drawable.setCallback(null);
        if(drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
            Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
            if (bmp != null && !bmp.isRecycled()){
                ((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(null);
                bmp.recycle();
                bmp =null;
                System.gc();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

My memory profiler:

[profiler memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwq7p.png)

I wonder how to release Graphics Memory.

Sorry, my English is not good and thanks for reading my question！

Comment: Try just to set image in this way.  `img.setImageResource(0)`

Comment: @GurgenArustamyan I have tried this method but it didn't have much effect.
Nonetheless, I still thank you for your reply !!